# How to properly type-check express route handler response

Tags: typescript, express

How do I properly type-check function with a return like this

`return res.status(200).send({ user, token });`

I have an express route handler type-checked as follows:

```
  type AuthResponse = {
    user: typeof Subscription;
    token: string;
  }

  type ErrorResponse = { error: string }

  async signUp(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response<AuthResponse | ErrorResponse>> {
    try {
      return res.status(200).send({ user, token });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error)
    }
  }
```

However the `Promise<Response<AuthResponse | ErrorResponse>>` type seems to have no effect. It doesn't flag when I return a response that doesn't match the response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS compiler can't infer the type of `res` based on what you pass to `res.send()`. You need to type the `res` argument like this and then you will get compiler / intellisense errors if you try to send the wrong type of data:

```
async signUp (
  req: Request, 
  res: Response<AuthResponse>, 
  next: NextFunction
)
```

Comment: Off-topic hint: NestJS for a better Typescript and overall dev-experience.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, I will find a way to port to NestJS.

Comment: Off topic, NestJS is terrible and type checking responses out of the box is harder than in express for some reason